# Computing random pair with Euclidean distance less than certain value

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to generate two (1D) points x1, x2 chosen randomly, and **independently**, from the uniform distribution U(-1,1) such that the euclidean distance between them is less than a certain value, dist. Here is one solution, but I'm looking for something more efficient:

```
def point_pair(low_=-1, hight_=1, dist = 0.001):
    while(1):
        x = np.random.uniform(low=low_, high=hight_)
        y = np.random.uniform(low=low_, high=hight_)
        length = np.linalg.norm(x-y)
        if length <= dist:
            return x,y
    return 0,0
```

Comment: OP, you're generating scalars; there's no need to call `linalg.norm`, you can simply subtract them. Did you actually mean to generate two X-Y coordinate pairs?

Comment: You could first pick a number x from -1 to 1, then pick another number y that is between max(-1, x-dist) and min(1, x+dist). But y will not be uniformly distributed between -1 and 1. On the other hand, with your method, neither x nor y will be uniformly distributed in that range. I think you need to think a little more about the joint distribution you expect for the pairs.

Comment: I am trying to generate two scalars

Comment: Then this has nothing to do with Euclidean distance.

Comment: @blorgon the real line is a Euclidean space. dist(x,y) = |x-y| makes perfect sense.

Comment: But isn't that the l1 norm? Euclidean distance refers specifically to the l2 norm, I thought.

Comment: You are trying to uniformly sample from a 6-sided polygon which is symmetric about the line `y=x`. I would look into the literature on sampling from polygons. See [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/14007/76877) for ideas.

Comment: @blorgon You can define `n`-dimensional Euclidean space in such a way that 1-dimensional is a special case `|x-y| = sqrt((x-y)**2)`.

Comment: No I get that, but I've always been under the impression that the term "Euclidean distance" *specifically referred to the l2 norm*.

Comment: The two norms that you refer to just happen to agree in 1-dimensional space.

Comment: I am sorry all, I need Euclidean distance to be less than dist. I going to update my question

Comment: @Juan does my answer help?

Comment: @blorgon I just had commented

Comment: These are inconsistent requirements.  The requirement that `x` and `y` are close forces them to _not_ be independent. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#Two_random_variables

Answer (score 2):

To generate two scalars whose magnitudes are close to each other:

```py
import numpy as np


def point_pair(low, high, dist):
    delta = np.random.uniform(-dist, dist)
    a = np.random.uniform(low + dist, high - dist)
    b = np.random.choice((-1, 1)) * a + delta
    return a, b
```

Your scalar `a` is generated almost in the same way, but where the bounds are not `[-1, 1)` but `[-1 + dist, 1 - dist)`. For `b`, you generate a new scalar which is uniformly distributed from `-dist` to `+dist`. This represents the bounds on the maximum distance away from `a` in either direction on the real line that you allow. Then `b` is simply `k*a + delta`, where again, `delta` is any value between `-dist` and `+dist`, and `k` is either `-1` or `1`.

This will ensure that both `a` and `b` are in `[-1, 1)` and that their magnitudes are similar, or `||a| - |b|| <= dist`.

### Note

The `np.random.uniform(low, high)` function always returns values in `[low, high)` so if you want to also include your upper bound, you'll need to use a different method.

Comment: I think this will generate points with coordinates outside (-1, 1).

Comment: @blorgon thanks I tried your, code, but it seems no be random uniform at (-1,1), because always both a and b are positive or negative.

Comment: @Jaun you're requirement that x and y be close will imply that they will almost always have the same sign as each other.  They will individually be (close to) uniformly distributed, but be far from independent.

Comment: Okay, so you need `||a| - |b|| <= dist`, the ***difference in magnitudes*** of `a` and `b` to be less than `dist`, not the ***difference in values?***

Comment: I just edited, yes I need them to be independent

Comment: Okay, well saying that you need "the Euclidean distance between them" less than a certain value *constrains* `a` and `b` to be close to each other. See @KyleParsons 's comment. You need to edit the OP to reflect what you ACTUALLY need, which is that their **magnitudes** be within a certain distance.

Comment: Also, if you truly want both `a` and `b` to be generated independently then your brute force method of generating values until they're similar is the only way that will be possible. You've honestly been so vague and confusing. I hope edited my answer helps.

Comment: @Juan I think it would help if you gave some examples of points that fit your requirements but would not be generated by this function, because this solution seems to solve your stated problem.

Answer (score -3):

use polar coordinates, your random numbers are angle and distance.

Comment: OP wants the two vectors to be a certain distance *from each other*, not the origin.

Comment: I don't see how that helps. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: There needs to be more detail here.  Say you uniformly choose a radius from 0 to 1 and uniformly choose an angle from 0 to 2pi.  Then half of your points will have radius < 1/2, but that is only 1/4 of the area of the circle.  You need to _non-uniformly_ sample radius to get a uniform distribution in the circle.  You also need to deal with the fact that the points need to be inside the unit circle.

Comment: distance is one of the parameters, so getting a random distance in the given range is trivial.  You still have to define what it means to be random within the [-1,1] box if both endpoints have to be inside, the density of vectors or the orientation of vectors can't be uniform.

Comment: @ddyer -1 and 1 are out of the range